# Laravel 5. Exceptions Handler / unique database field

Tags: php, laravel, exception, laravel-4, laravel-5

I want to avoid the following error:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry
```

This is displayed on my screen when I try to add an email which already exists in the database. So I want to replace this error screen with a customized error message displayed in a view.

This is what I tried:

```
//inside app/Exceptions/Handler.php

public function render($request, Exception $e)
{  
    if ($e instanceof ModelNotFoundException) {
        $e = new NotFoundHttpException($e->getMessage(), $e);
    }                

    if ($e instanceof Illuminate\Database\QueryException){
        if($e->errorInfo[1] == 1062){
            // But It never reaches this point
        }
    }

    return parent::render($request, $e);
}
```

The error code is indeed 1062, but the problem is that it does not pass this:

```
if ($e instanceof Illuminate\Database\QueryException)
```

Do you know why, or what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What happens if you catch by this `catch (Illuminate\Database\QueryException $e)`  & checking for `$errorCode = $e->errorInfo[1];` ?

Comment: Well I wanted to keep an order inside the render function. Keep all the if's the same.

Comment: Ok, but you can't catch using this ? `catch (Illuminate\Database\QueryException $e)` , and then `if($e->errorInfo[1] == 1062){ //it might reach here  }`

Comment: To be specific `catch (Illuminate\Database\QueryException $e){
    if($e->errorInfo[1] == 1062){
        // throw here
    }
}` . Is this working for you ?

Comment: Also you don't want to do [validatoin](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation) ?

Comment: Ok inside the Query Exception, What happens if you print `$e->errorInfo[1]` ?

Answer (score 1):

> If nothing works the worst answer is to remove the unique key from 'email' field in db.

But I think what you need is validation, also you can set custom error message for each fields.

reference:  http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/validation#custom-error-messages

### Controller file

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $v = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'name' => 'required|min:5',
            'email' => 'required|email|unique:users,email',
            'password' => 'required|min:6',
            'confirm_password' => 'required|min:6|same:password'
        ]);

    if ($v->fails())
    {
        return redirect()->back()->withErrors($v->errors());
    }

    //do success actions here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for `23000 Error code (integrity_constraint_violation)`. If you take a look at [`QueryException`][1] class, it extends from [`PDOException`][2], so you can access to `$errorInfo` variable.

To catch this error, you may try:

```
try {
  // ...

} catch ( \Illuminate\Database\QueryException $e) {
    var_dump($e->errorInfo );
}

// example output 
array (size=3)
   0 => string '23000' (length=5)
   1 => int 1452
   2 => string 'Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (...)'
```

Answer (score 0):

The namespace in the question reference code seems malformed.

instead of
`Illuminate\Database\QueryException`

it should be
`\Illuminate\Database\QueryException`